# Invalid latlng object - React Leaflet

Tags: reactjs, openstreetmap, latitude-longitude, geocode, react-leaflet

```
  const [geoData, setGeoData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const forGeoCode = await axios(
        "https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=United%20States&key={accessToken}&language=en&pretty=1"
      );
      setGeoData(forGeoCode.data.results[0].geometry);
    })();
  }, []);
  console.log(geoData.geometry);
  return (
    <div>
      <Map center={[52.6376, -1.135171]} zoom={12}>
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        />
        <Marker position={[geoData.lat, geoData.lng]} />
      </Map>
```

The above code gives me the following error: Error: Invalid LatLng object: (undefined, undefined)

console.log prints in longitude and latitude but i'm still getting error.

Expected behavior: Take United States as input and return its longitudes and latitudes and plot it on map

Comment: Where is geoCode defined?

Comment: There was a typo. It should be `geoData` instead of `geoCode`

Comment: You need to wait until the effect / loading is done before rendering the marker.

Comment: @Stuck How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize geoData like array empty `[]`

You should initialize:

```js
const [geoData, setGeoData] = useState({lat:null,lng:null});
```

And in return of your component, you should change that Marker only paint when geoData lat and lng are different to null (it would be when you receive data in response axios):

```js
return (
    <div>
      <Map center={[52.6376, -1.135171]} zoom={12}>
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        />
        {geoData.lat && geoData.lng && <Marker position={[geoData.lat, geoData.lng]} />}
      </Map>
```

And in `useEffect` I recommend you to use promise with `then` and `catch` to improve user experience. Only in then you must to use `setGeoData` and overwrite properties `lat` and `lng`

```js
useEffect(() => {
      axios.get(
        "https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=United%20States&key={accessToken}&language=en&pretty=1"
      ).then(response => {
       // I expect in response object geometry, change by the correct route
       setGeoData(response.data.geometry);
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log("error",err);
      });
  }, []);
```

-------- NEXT QUESTION --------

If you want to edit styles of map.

As you can see in docs in React-Leaflet: [Link here](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/components#map)

You can add props like className or style.

The result it would be

```js
<Map style={{width:"400px",height:"600px"}}>
...
```

Comment: I got this error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {lat, lng}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Are you painting in some part of code geoData? You can't paint object in react, you only can paint properties of object, check if you paint geoData alone in return

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. This is my code: https://codesandbox.io/embed/delicate-rgb-tyl9i?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: You are painting  <textPath>{geoData}</textPath>. You can put properties of geoData, not geoData Object. If you delete this, Map works. What do you want to render inside textPath?

Comment: Yeah gotcha. I forgot to remove <textPath>. Also my map loads full screen, how can I style it to fit in a box of dimensions 600px by 400px?

Comment: I will add in answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212002/discussion-between-killme-and-adrian-naranjo).

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Coords {
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
}

const [geoData, setGeoData] = useState<Coords>({
    lat: 52.6376,
    lng: -1.135171,
  });
```

You need to initialize the values of lat and lng. Hope this helps. thank you.